# Как заменить id на username?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Помогите, как заменить id на username?

Например:

```
id     | username
1        Andrei
2        Nikolai
3        Pavel
```

и например:

```
Имя: <?php $userdata(id_1); ?> =>   Имя: Andrei
Имя: <?php $userdata(id_2); ?> =>   Имя: Nikolai
Имя: <?php $userdata(id_3); ?> =>   Имя: Pavel.
```

Помогите, я новичок, как можно сделать? Мне очень нужно! Пожалуйста, если можно, расскажите подробно...

Comment: Судя по тегам все данные у вас хранятся в БД. Вопрос только - а как вы id получаете? Никак? Т.е. надо просто из базы выбрать несколько id и username? Или список id вы получили заранее и по ним вам надо получить соответствующий список username?

Какими знаниями вы обладаете? Можете подключиться к БД, выполнить запрос и получить из него данные? Или вам это тоже надо объяснять?

Comment: Да хранятся в БД. Мне просто показать например я пищу: "Имя <?php $блабла(здесь не имя(username), просто поставлю id пользователя)?>". Например id_1 = Andrei и "Имя Andrei"

Comment: Вам потребуется что-то типа функции:

    function nameById($id) {
        $id = intval($id);
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
        $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = {$id}";
        $queryResult = $mysqli->query($query);
        $userRow = $queryResult->fetch_assoc();
        return $userRow['username'];
    }
    echo nameById(1000);

Но для начала надо бы попрактиковаться. Как работать с mysql можно посмотреть в [примерах](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!! ВОРОН спасибо большое за внимание! Все работает!

Comment: Это только пример. Его не стоит использовать в реальном проекте. Только в качестве отправной точки для дальнейшего погружения.

Пара проблем моего примера:

- не проверяются ошибки
- при каждом вызове функции устанавливается соединение с БД
- если будет куча таких функций и сменится логин/пароль к БД (либо надо будет делать каждый раз дополнительные действия), то менять придется везде (что чревато ошибками из-за невнимательности)

Если вынести работу с БД в отдельный класс, то таких проблем можно будет избежать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот небольшой пример класса-обертки для mysqli:

```
class MysqliWrapper
{
    protected static $instance = null;
    protected $mysqli = null;

    protected function __construct()
    {
        $host = "Localhost";
        $user = "language";
        $password = "language";
        $db = "language";
        $connect_error = "MySQL сервер недоступен!";
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);
        if ($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
            throw new Exception($connect_error);
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!static::$instance) {
            static::$instance = new static();
        }
        return static::$instance;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->mysqli, $name), $arguments);
    }
}
```

Сначала получаете экземпляр класса, а затем работаете с ним так же, как и с mysqli. Например, функцию из моего комментария можно переписать в виде:

```
function function nameById($id)
{
    $id = intval($id);
    $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = {$id}";
    $db = MysqliWrapper::getInstance();
    $queryResult = $db->query($query);
    if (!$queryResult) {
        return 'Error';
    }
    $userRow = $queryResult->fetch_assoc();
    return $userRow['username'];
}
```

Если надо будет изменить используемую БД, то можно сделать так же, как и для mysqli:

```
$db = MysqliWrapper::getInstance();
if (!$db->select_db('new_db_name')) {
    die('Ошибка при смене БД');
}
```

Только в данном случае надо помнить следующее: поскольку используется один экземпляр, то после смены БД она сменится везде. Например, здесь будет ошибка:

```
$db1 = MysqliWrapper::getInstance();
$db1->select_db('db_with_users');
$db1->query("SELECT * FROM users"); // выполнится нормально
...

$db2 = MysqliWrapper::getInstance();
$db2->select_db('db_without_users');
$db2->query("SELECT * FROM goods"); // выполнится нормально
...

$db1->query("SELECT * FROM users"); // БД сменили, поэтому не выполнится
...
```

Избежать этого можно, например, так:

```
$db = MysqliWrapper::getInstance();
$db->query("SELECT * FROM db_with_users.users"); // выполнится нормально
$db->query("SELECT * FROM db_without_users.goods"); // выполнится нормально
$db->query("SELECT * FROM db_with_users.users"); // выполнится нормально
```

Comment: Спасибо, ВОРОН, все работает!