# Нужна помощь в создании обертки для подготовленного запроса SELECT

Tags: php, mysqli, классы, select, функции

Пытаюсь сделать обертку для select запроса, но никак не пойму как передать пустые переменные функции, есть следующий код:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");


$query = "SELECT id, first_name FROM test";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($id, $first_name);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    echo $id; 
    echo $first_name;

}

$stmt->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Если я правильно понимаю:

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $first_name);
```

присваивает переменным:

```
$id, $first_name
```

значения: id, first_name, из БД

В данном примере всё работает!

Но как на основе этого сделать класс? Вернее я сделал, но как передать переменные в:

```
$stmt->bind_result(Сюда);
```

Прошу простить, может вопрос глупый или не совсем понятный, но я пока учусь.

Сам класс, вернее набросок:

```
<? 
class mysqliAction {

    public function __construct($mysqli_server, $mysqli_user,     $mysqli_password, $mysqli_database) {

    $this->s = $mysqli_server;
    $this->u = $mysqli_user;
    $this->p = $mysqli_password;
    $this->d = $mysqli_database;

}

protected function connect() {

    return new mysqli($this->s,$this->u,$this->p,$this->d);

}

public function mysqliSelect($query) {

    $mysqli = $this->connect();

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    $stmt->execute();

/* Определить переменные для результата */
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $first_name);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

  echo   $id; 
  echo $first_name;

}

$stmt->close();

}
}


$mysqli = new mysqliAction($mysqli_server, $mysqli_user, $mysqli_password,     $mysqli_database);

$query = 'SELECT id, first_name FROM test';

$mysqli->mysqliSelect($query);

?>
```

Так всё работает, но как передавать аргументы в:

```
  $stmt->bind_result($id, $first_name, и так далее);
```

Comment: @BOPOH, добавил класс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создавать свои параметры можно примерно таким образом: `$$name_var`

В вашем же случае можно подавать массив, с списком полей и вызывать callback функцию

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'parent::bind_result'), array("\$id","\$first_name"));
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можете показать на примере данного кода если не сложно, читал про `call_user_func_array`, но как-то не могу понять...

Comment: А чем плох этот вариант? 
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Я читал что подготовленные запросы более безопасны, и производительны (поправьте если ошибаюсь), я хочу сделать класс-обертку для SELECT, INSERT, и так далее.

Comment: но у вас уже теряется производительность, вы постоянно вызываете connect (новое соединение с базой), нежели держать его ссылку, которую можно создавать в конструкторе.

Comment: Так она и создается в конструкторе, и вызывается при запросе... Или я что-то не так понял? И кажется мы отошли от темы))) Всё же как использовать `call_user_func_array`, в моем коде? Ткните носом)

Comment: @ВадимПедченко, "подготавливаете" вы через `$mysqli->prepare($query);` а через `mysqli_fetch_assoc` вы уже получаете результат выполнения запроса. Т.е. использование `mysqli_fetch_assoc` никоим образом не влияет на вашу безопасность. Если вы сделаете `$mysqli->prepare("select id from table where field = $field"); $stmt->bind_result($id);`, то проблемы с безопасностью обеспечены

Comment: @BOPOH, Руководствуюсь мануалом: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @ВадимПедченко, вы не так его поняли. "Подготавливают" так: `$mysqli->prepare("select id from table where field = ?"); $stmt->bind_param("i", $id); $stmt->execute();` Т.е. все данные от пользователя (и не только от него) вы пропускаете через `bind_param`, задав для них соответствующие вопросики в запросе. А после этого можно хоть как получать данные, хоть через `bind_result`, хотя через `mysqli_fetch_assoc` - запрос вы уже выполнили, поэтому ничего страшного не случится. А грубый пример того, что вам предлагали, можете посмотреть [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/399506/5079)

Comment: @BOPOH, Ок пусть будет fetch_assoc))) Но как передать параметры: bind_param("i", $id //Сюда), в функцию?