# Правильная модель структуры организации функционала для работы с базой данных

Tags: php, mysqli

Как правильно структурировать функции в php файлах для работы с базой данных?
На данный момент я придерживаюсь следующей структуры:
Имеется один большой php класс(database.class.php) в котором описаны методы взаимодействия компонентов сайта с базой данных. Т.е. в классе собраны все методы для работы с базой данных.

```
class DataBase
{
    private $mysqlSession; 

    public function __construct($mysqlip, $mysqluser, $mysqlpassword, $db, $mysqlport)
    {
        $this->mysqlSession = new mysqli($mysqlip, $mysqluser, $mysqlpassword, $db, $mysqlport);

        if($this->mysqlSession->connect_errno)
            exit("Could not connect to MySQL: (".$this->mysqlSession->connect_errno.") ".$this->mysqlSession->connect_error);

        if(!$this->mysqlSession->set_charset("utf8"))
            exit("Error loading the character set utf8: ".$this->mysqlSession->error);
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->mysqlSession->close();
    }

    function getModelsByIdMark($id)
    {
        if($stmt = $this->mysqlSession->prepare("SELECT * FROM `models` WHERE id_mark=? ORDER BY `id` ASC"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $stmt->close();
        }
        else
            exit("Failed to prepare a request "."(".$this->mysqlSession->errno .") ".$this->mysqlSession->error);

        return $result;
    }       

    function getMarks()
    {
        ...
    }       

    function getCitys()
    {
        ...
    }       

    function getCats()
    {
        ...
    }

    function getOrderById($id)
    {
        ...
    }   

    function createorder($name, $cityid, $email, $idmark, $idmodel, $idcat, $comment, $file, $phone = 0)
    {
        ...
    }

    function addcomment($name, $email, $comment, $ip)
    {
        ...
    }

    function log($name, $logmsg, $loglevel = 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

На одном из форумов я прочитал, что можно использовать ещё одну модель, создать для каждого модуля сайта свой класс и записывать методы для работы с базой данных в него, но тогда встаёт вопрос: если использовать на одной странице 2 модуля(компонента), то будет открыто 2 соединения с базой данных.

```
class Order
{
    private $mysqlSession; 
    ... // Other attr

    public function __construct($mysqlip, $mysqluser, $mysqlpassword, $db, $mysqlport)
    {
        $this->mysqlSession = new mysqli($mysqlip, $mysqluser, $mysqlpassword, $db, $mysqlport);

        if($this->mysqlSession->connect_errno)
            exit("Could not connect to MySQL: (".$this->mysqlSession->connect_errno.") ".$this->mysqlSession->connect_error);

        if(!$this->mysqlSession->set_charset("utf8"))
            exit("Error loading the character set utf8: ".$this->mysqlSession->error);
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->mysqlSession->close();
    }

    function getOrderById($id)
    {
        ...
    }   

    function createorder($name, $cityid, $email, $idmark, $idmodel, $idcat, $comment, $file, $phone = 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class Comment
{
    private $mysqlSession; 
    ... // Other attr

    public function __construct($mysqlip, $mysqluser, $mysqlpassword, $db, $mysqlport)
    {
        $this->mysqlSession = new mysqli($mysqlip, $mysqluser, $mysqlpassword, $db, $mysqlport);

        if($this->mysqlSession->connect_errno)
            exit("Could not connect to MySQL: (".$this->mysqlSession->connect_errno.") ".$this->mysqlSession->connect_error);

        if(!$this->mysqlSession->set_charset("utf8"))
            exit("Error loading the character set utf8: ".$this->mysqlSession->error);
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->mysqlSession->close();
    }

    function deletecomment($id)
    {
        ...
    }   

    function addcomment($name, $email, $comment, $ip)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Каким способом лучше организовать хранение методов для работы с базой данных?

Comment: ну так можно же создать класс для работы с базой и использовать его. Т.е. выбрасываете все из вашего конструктора Order и делаете там: $db = DataBase::getInstance(); А дальше работаете уже с этим объектом как сейчас. Аналогично и в других классах. Только явно закрывать соединение в этих классах не надо. Пример того, как это может выглядеть можно посмотреть в [моем ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/399506/5079)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта так себе.

Вот этот код,

```
    if($stmt = $this->mysqlSession->prepare("SELECT * FROM `models` WHERE id_mark=? ORDER BY `id` ASC"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else
        exit("Failed to prepare a request "."(".$this->mysqlSession->errno .") ".$this->mysqlSession->error);
```

-- это *очень* плохо.
Программист придет от него в ужас.

Значимых частей в нем на одну строчку -

- `"SELECT * FROM`models`WHERE id_mark=? ORDER BY`id`ASC"` и `$id`

Всё остальное - ненужный мусор, повторяемый при *каждом* обращении к БД.  Метод getModelsByIdMark() должен выглядеть так:

```
function getModelsByIdMark($id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `models` WHERE id_mark=? ORDER BY `id` ASC";
    return $this->db->method($sql, [$id]);
}
```

причем возвращать он должен данные **сразу в нужном формате,** а не в виде mysqli_result, с которым потом еще дополнительно придется колупаться. Если ожидается одна строка - то одномерный массив или объект. Если ожидается много строк - то список, состоящий из одномерных массивов или объектов.

**Всё остальное должна делать программа.**

Потому что именно в этом и состоит смысл программирования - в автоматизации рутинных повторяющихся операций.

То есть, правильной структурой будет

- Класс для выполнения операций с БД. **Mysqli на роль этого класса не подходит.**
- Специальный сервис для передачи единственного объекта для работы с БД в другие классы, чтобы не дублировалось соединение с БД. Это может быть прямая передача, или какие-нибудь модные контейнеры, или презираемый синглтон.
- Отдельные классы, которые содержат всю логику для работы с БД для каждого модуля.

Поздравляю, ты изобрел "модель", в том смысле как ее понимают все современные фреймворки! Потому что именно так в них устроена работа с БД.

В самом примитивном случае на роль класса для работы с БД подойдет PDO c передачей инстанса напрямую. Тогда твои модели будут выглядеть так:

```
class Comment
{
    private $db; 
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;

    function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->prepare("SELECT FROM comments WHERE id=?")->execute([$id]);
    }   

    function add($name, $email, $comment, $ip)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)";
        $this->db->prepare($sql)->execute([$name, $email, $comment, $ip]);
    }
}
```

Хотя лучше конечно сделать нормальный ОРМ, чтобы не писать такой примитив, как addcomment вручную вообще - методы add и delete будут наследоваться от родительского класса, и писать руками надо будет только вещи типа getModelsByIdMark.

При наличии же квери билдера такой простой запрос можно сразу записать в контроллере как

```
$models = Model::where('id_mark',$id);
```

и в модель тоже не писать.

В общем, надо учить современные технологии, а не колупаться с mysqli_query, как тут советуют некоторые.

Comment: Я правильно вас понял? http://pastebin.com/kk2bhywL

Comment: В общем и целом верно, только обязательно прочитать http://phpfaq.ru/pdo и выкинуть ВСЕ эти чудовищные try..catch из кода. Плюс для проверки $dbh не надо писать код вручную, надо просто написать, в параметрах, что ожидается инстанс класса PDO: `__construct(\PDO $dbh, $initarray = null)`. Плюс вместо всего этого чудовищно длинного кода с присвоением свойств, написать одну строчку, `$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this);`

Comment: В итоге функция должна выглядеть так: http://pastebin.com/cp7eWBUe только не забыть поменять свойства на публичные. В приватных как бы проку не очень много

Comment: Огромное спасибо